# No explanation of O2 when "clang --help"

Tags: clang

I want to know why

```
clang --help
```

does not show any explanation for options like -O1, -O2 or -O3 ? Any idea?

My OS is Mac OS 10.9.5.

Comment: ... and `man clang` contains section `Code Generation Options` about it.

Comment: @Nikolay - not really: "Moderate level of optimization which enables most optimizations." - is almost a recursive definition:)